# Fixing the wx.lib.pubsub has been depreciated, please migrate your code to use pypubsub error

Tags: python, pypubsub

I am having this error `wx.lib.pubsub has been depreciated, please migrate your code to use pypubsub`, every time i try and run a particular application. I've seen this been answered with installing "pypubsub"

and then replacing the line `from wx.lib.pubsub import pub` to `from pubsub import pub`.

I'm not a technical guru and i have no idea what file they are editing here when they make this change. if somebody knows how to do this, I would appreciate it if you would point me in the right direction

I've looked into all the files under the pypubsub folder hoping to find the file i need to make these changes too.

Answer (score 0):

The install for `PySubPub` as stated in the documentation [PySubPub](https://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.3/installation.html#how-to) mentions running in a command prompt or terminal emulator:

```
pip install pypubsub
```

Then [pypubsub](https://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.3/usage/usage_basic.html) can be used in your python script as shown in the documentation [Quick Start](https://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.3/usage/usage_basic.html#quick-start) 
 `Simplest example of use`:

```
"""
One listener is subscribed to a topic called 'rootTopic'.
One 'rootTopic' message gets sent. 
"""

from pubsub import pub


# ------------ create a listener ------------------

def listener1(arg1, arg2=None):
    print('Function listener1 received:')
    print('  arg1 =', arg1)
    print('  arg2 =', arg2)


# ------------ register listener ------------------

pub.subscribe(listener1, 'rootTopic')

# ---------------- send a message ------------------

print('Publish something via pubsub')
anObj = dict(a=456, b='abc')
pub.sendMessage('rootTopic', arg1=123, arg2=anObj)
```

> Running the above as a script (available in the docs/usage folder of
> the source distribution as helloworld.py) will produce the result:

```
Publish something via pubsub
Function listener1 received:
  arg1 = 123
  arg2 = {'a': 456, 'b': 'abc'}
```

Comment: haha i know the issue now, the application i'm trying to run is already written and compiled, and i'm not the one that wrote it. Does this mean you'd have to get the source code fix the code there and then build the software from scratch?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, because does [PySubPub](https://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.3/installation.html#how-to) not work [Out of the Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)) with your application ? As such, the PyPubSub library should not need any fix to its source code to run your application